# How to dynamically Constrain range of coverage item in specman?

Tags: specman, function-coverage

Signal x is a one hot signal of bits 'n' 
I would like to cover only one hot values of the signal and not interested in other values.

Ex: if a signal x is of 3 bits then I would like does x is reaching below values are not.

```
x == 3'b001
x == 3'b010
x == 3'b100
```

I tried below to achieve goal.

```
struct ABC {
 x :uint(bits:n);
 event pqrs;
 cover pqrs is {
   item x using ranges={
                         range([1]);
                         range([2]);
                         range([4]);
                       };
 };
```

But above code is not elegant since 'n' `define value which can be varied based on environment.
Please help me how to write coverage for above case.

Thanking all in advance for your help.
Regards,
Srikanth

Answer (score 1):

you cam write a simple 'define as computed' macro to do so.
i have written a short example below.

the macro should look like this :

```
 define <RANGE1'struct_member> "COVER_ITEM_WITH_DEFAULT_RANGES <struct_member>" as computed { 

var x:uint(bits:NBITS) = 1;
var str := append( "cover covT_e is also {",
  "item ", <1>," using ranges = {");
while(x!=0){
    str =append(str,"range([",x,"]);");
    x=x<<1;
};
  str=append(str,        "};",
                  "}"
                );
return str;
};
```

and the you can use that in your code like so :

```
<'
define NBITS 4;
import cover0;

extend sys {

 field1 : uint(bits:NBITS);
event covT_e;

cover covT_e is empty;          

COVER_ITEM_WITH_DEFAULT_RANGES field1;

run() is also {
    for i from 1 to 20 {
        gen field1;
          emit covT_e;
        print field1;
    }; // for i from 1 to...
}; // run() is also


finalize() is also{
    specman("show cover");
};
}; // extend sys
'>
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can write yourself a define-as-computed macro that creates the covergroup. 
Note that the macro must expand to the full syntactic element, you cannot just create a macro that creates the range expressions.
(I have such a macro but cannot disclose it).

Thorsten.